# Calculating difficulty and target with 256 bits

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, hash, proof-of-work, difficulty

Why do the yellow paper and Ethereum implementations use `2**256` instead of `2**256 - 1` when calculating hash target from difficulty?

The Ethereum Yellow Paper uses `2**256 / difficulty` to define the target as part of the proof-of-work function.

go-ethereum also uses `2**256` [to calculate target](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L583):

```go
target := new(big.Int).Div(two256, header.Difficulty)
```

However, the maximum value that a 256-bit hash can take is `2**256 - 1`.

[image: yellow paper target]

Comment: What the problem exactly? It looks like a simplification for making the computation. In any case you have to use arbitrary precision integers, so 256 bits or 257 bits are much different.

Comment: It's not a problem, but I wondered if there is a mathematical reason for using `2^256` instead of `2^256 - 1`.

If it were 256 bits I think that you could implement this using a uint256 type instead of an arbitrary precision integer.